# Image Block Processing

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have a large image, and I want to process it block by block (512 x 512) at a time. I am currently doing this with loops, but I know that it is not the most efficient way to do this. What else can I use to make it more optimized?

Comment: What does the processing do? post your code. If they are not dependant then multi-process can be the way to go.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post my code. But I will tell you what it does: I basically have 2 nested loops that take 512 x 512 one at a time. In the inner loop, I perform image segmentation and classification. What do you mean by multiprocess?

Comment: Python threading is 'fake', due to the GIL. If the processing of each block is not dependant on the other blocks, you could start a process for each one of the blocks, and they will process it in parallel.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot tell how to optimize code we cannot see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide the image into several `multiprocess.Array`, process each one separately on a different process, then reconstruct the image.
Here some toy example to get you started:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Value, Array
import numpy as np


def processBlock(arr,i): #Image Processing function, i is an extra argument i used for the process.
    block = np.frombuffer(arr.get_obj())
    block = block.reshape((512,512,3))
    #Some processing
    block[:] = i
    ############
    block = block.reshape((-1))
    arr[:] = block


fullImage = np.zeros((512*2,512*2,3)) #Create full image of 0s
imageParts = []
imageParts.append(Array('d',fullImage[0:512,512:,:].flatten())) #Divide it into 4 parts
imageParts.append(Array('d',fullImage[0:512,0:512,:].flatten()))
imageParts.append(Array('d',fullImage[512:,0:512,:].flatten()))
imageParts.append(Array('d',fullImage[512:,512:,:].flatten()))
processes = []
for i in range(4): #Process each part simulatinously 
    p = Process(target = processBlock, args=(imageParts[i],i))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for i in range(4): #Wait for all
    processes[i].join()

#Reconstruct Image
fullImage[0:512,512:,:] = np.frombuffer(imageParts[0].get_obj()).reshape((512,512,3))
fullImage[0:512,0:512,:] = np.frombuffer(imageParts[1].get_obj()).reshape((512,512,3))
fullImage[512:,0:512,:] = np.frombuffer(imageParts[2].get_obj()).reshape((512,512,3))
fullImage[512:,512:,:] = np.frombuffer(imageParts[3].get_obj()).reshape((512,512,3))
```

Comment: I was just looking for a tutorial to help me get started with multiprocessing. Thank you very much!!