# Multithreading image processing in python

Tags: python, multithreading, image-processing

I have an image processing application written in python that does the following:

- get an image I from the camera
- perform a processing step P1 on I, obtaining I1
- perform another processing step P2 on I1, obtaining I2

P1 and P2 are performed with external USB co-processors. I want to use threading to run P1 and P2 in parallel. My idea is to set I, I1 and I2 as global variables and do something like this:

Camera thread:

```
while alive:
    lock.acquire()
    I = videoCapture.read()
    lock.release()
```

P1 thread:

```
while alive:
    lock.acquire()
    I1 = doSomeProcessing(I)
    lock.release()
```

P2 thread:

```
while alive:
    lock.acquire()
    I2 = doOtherProcessing(I1)
    lock.release()
```

Main thread:

```
CameraThread.start()
P1Thread.start()
P2Thread.start()

while True:
    lock.acquire()
    doSomething(I2)
    lock.release()
```

The first thread has a higher execution speed while the other two are similar. For now, I want P1 to process the most recent image (it's fine if images are skipped) and I don't care if P2 process the same I1 twice or if P2 skips some images.

I'm new to multithreading and I am not sure that this is the correct logic to optimize the execution. In particular, the main thread should retrieve I2 only when a new output is produced. What should I change in this pipeline?

Comment: You will need to use multi-processing, python multi-threading is not real (due to the `GIL` - Global Interpreter Lock). There's a toy example i have written for image multi process processing here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476711/image-block-processing/53477238#53477238